# How to use SAS code to update data from another table

Tags: sql, sas

I'm good in SQL but is new to SAS.
I'm doing ETL from 3rd party application database to own database.
This ETL will execute daily.
So I need to insert new record and also update existing records to my database.
Insert is not problem, but I'm not too sure how to do the update using SAS code.
So, I try to use SQL to do the task...
Problem here is I have to do subquery for each column needed to update, I feel the update will be slow cause too many subquery needed.
So I want to ask is there any way I can make the update run fast?

```
CREATE TABLE TmpProfile AS
SELECT src.member_name AS Name
      ,src.ic_no as IDNo
      ,src.status AS Status
      ,src.Address AS Address
      ,src.State_Code AS StateCode
      ,src.Country AS Country
      ,src.Mobile_No as MobileNo
FROM   source.Members src
WHERE  src.IDNo NOT IN (SELECT IDNo
                        FROM   mydb.Members)
AND    NOT MISSING(src.IDNo);

INSERT INTO mydb.MembersProfile (Name, IDNo, Status, Address, StateCode, Country, MobileNo)
SELECT Name, IDNo, Status, Address, State_Code, Country, MobileNo FROM TmpProfile;

UPDATE mydb.MembersProfile 
SET    status = (SELECT status FROM source.Members WHERE MembersProfile.IDNo = Members.ic_no)
      ,Address = (SELECT Address FROM source.Members WHERE MembersProfile.IDNo = Members.ic_no)
      ,StateCode = (SELECT State_Code FROM source.Members WHERE MembersProfile.IDNo = Members.ic_no)          
      ,Country = (SELECT Country FROM source.Members WHERE MembersProfile.IDNo = Members.ic_no)
      ,MobileNo = (SELECT Mobile_No FROM source.Members WHERE MembersProfile.IDNo = Members.ic_no)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can two SQL statements, one to update and one to insert

```
data master master_2;
  do id = 1 to 20 by 3;
    x = id * 2;
    output;
  end;
run;

data etl;
  do id = 1 to 20 by 2;
    x = id * 3;
    output;
  end;
run;

proc sql;
  update master 
  set x = (select x from etl where etl.id = master.id)
  where exists (select * from etl where etl.id = master.id);
  ;

  reset undo_policy = none;

  insert into master
  select * from etl where etl.id not in (select id from master)
  ;
quit;
```

Alternatively, you can use SAS `MODIFY` statement to update a data set in place.
Data set indices are used to make the process possible.

```
proc sql;
  create index id on master_2;
  create index id on etl;

data master_2;
  set etl;
  modify master_2 key=id;

  if _iorc_ ne 0 then do;  * etl id not in master, new record;
    _error_ = 0;
    output;
  end;
  else do; * etl id in master, re-read the etl record that had its vars overwritten when modify statement was reached;
    set etl key=id;
    replace;  * rewrite observation in place;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: update master 
  set x = (select x from etl where etl.id = master.id)
  where exists (select * from etl where etl.id = master.id);

I have more than 20 columns to update, each column will need a subquery, isn't that slow performance??

Comment: Yes, 20 separate updates using `SET <column> = <subquery>` will likely be less efficient than other techniques such as using the data step `MODIFY ... KEY=` statement, or an equivalent hash based ETL lookup approach.  Base SAS `PROC SQL` does **not** support setting tuples (i.e. `set x,y,z = (select etlx, etly, etlz from ...`)